# How Can we use Heterogeneous key in TreeMap

Tags: java

On executing below mentioned code I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.tree.T1 cannot be cast to com.test.tree.T2
    at com.test.tree.TestComparator.compare(TestTreeMap.java:59)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:530)
    at com.test.tree.TestTreeMap.main(TestTreeMap.java:22)
```

Code:

```
package com.test.tree;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class TestTreeMap{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TreeMap tree=new TreeMap(new TestComparator());
        T1 t1=new T1(10, 20);
        T2 t2=new T2(10,21);
        tree.put(t1, 23);
        tree.put(t2, 24);
    }

}
class T1 {
   int x,y;

    public T1(int x, int y) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}


}
class T2 {
   int x,y;
    public T2(int x,int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
}

}

class TestComparator implements Comparator{

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        System.out.println("hi im called");
        T1 t1=(T1)o1;
        T2 t2=(T2)o2;
        return t1.x-t2.y;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assume that `compare` will always receive a `T1` instance as the first argument and a `T2` instance as the second. It may receive two `T1` instances or two `T2` instances, or instances of both, but not in the order you expect.

You have to test the types of `o1` and `o2` before casting them to `T1` or `T2`.

```
@Override
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    if (o1 instanceof T1) {
        if (o2 instanceof T2) {
            T1 t1=(T1)o1;
            T2 t2=(T2)o2;
            return t1.x-t2.y;
        } else {
           ...
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is assuming the keys of your `TreeMap` can only be either `T1` or `T2`.

Comment: Thanks @Eran, i was bit confused

Comment: but if there is  multiple types candidates for key.......Then any generalized way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in two separate clases so far, just use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TreeMap tree=new TreeMap(new TestComparator());
    T1 t1=new T1(10, 20);
    T1 t2=new T1(10, 21);
    tree.put(t1, 23);
    tree.put(t2, 24);
}
```

Or inherit class `T2` from class `T1` and use:

```
class TestComparator implements Comparator{

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        System.out.println("hi im called");
        T1 t1=(T1)o1;
        T1 t2=(T1)o2;
        return t1.x-t2.y;
    }

}
```

Or declare some formal interface, which must be implemented by both `T1` and `T2` classes, and allows to handle comparision flawlesly no matter what arguments are:

```
interface Comparable {
    int comparisonToken();
}

class T1 implements Comparable {
    int comparisonToken() {
        return this.x;
    }
    ...
}

class T2 implements Comparable {
    int comparisonToken() {
        return this.y;
    }
    ...
}

class TestComparator implements Comparator{

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        System.out.println("hi im called");
        Comparable t1= (Comparable)o1;
        Comparable t2= (Comparable)o2;
        return t1.comparisonToken() - t2.comparisonToken();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add the generics; using raw types like this is not a very good idea.

Comment: @ankhzet there may be some scenario where we have to use multiple types of Object as Key

Comment: Then you should define some basic comparable interface for all of them, and use it in comparator, as i suggested

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
 @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        System.out.println("hi im called");
        T1 t1 = null;
        T2 t2 = null;
        if(o1 instanceof T1){
            t1=(T1)o1;
        } else if(o1 instanceof T2){
            t2 = (T2)o1;
        }
        if(o2 instanceof T2){
            t2=(T2)o2;
            return t1.x-t2.y;
        } else{
            t1 = (T1)o2;
            return t1.x-t1.y;

        }

        }
```